# Getting Clear Text Index of WPF RichTextBox Selection

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I need to be able to highlight multiple blocks of plain text given a start index and length inside an editable control. Now I know that it's not possible to do this with a regular TextBox so am looking at using a RichTextBox instead. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find what the clear text index would be from the selected text inside a RichTextBox.

I can add a background colour easily enough to a selection, but I need to be able to get at the clear text index of where the selection is and the length of the selection (which seems easy enough) as this is what is getting stored in a database.

Any help is greatly appreciated - this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Why do you need index and length?

Comment: I need it as users need to be able to tag parts of text. While editing data, I need to highlight sections to show that they have been tagged (hence the use of RTB) but all I need to store is the block of text and a list of start indices and lengths that represent the tagged selections.